# How to static compile python on centos 8?

Tags: python, linux, centos8

I am using the `centos:8` docker file and trying to compile python (with the static flag and openssl).
This is my docker file:

```
FROM centos:8

RUN dnf update -y
RUN yum -y install dnf-plugins-core
RUN dnf config-manager --enable powertools
RUN dnf -y builddep python3
RUN dnf -y install wget
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/Python-3.9.6.tgz
RUN tar xzvf Python*
COPY ./Setup /Python-3.9.6/Modules/Setup
RUN dnf install -y gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel wget make glibc-static glibc-common glibc-devel openssl
RUN cd Python*/ && ./configure --with-system-ffi --with-computed-gotos --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions LDFLAGS="-static" --disable-shared && make LDFLAGS="-static" LINKFORSHARED=" "
```

This is the change I did to Modules/Setup:

```
# Socket module helper for socket(2)
_socket socketmodule.c

# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
SSL=/usr/include/openssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
 -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
 -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

This is the error:

```
libpython3.9.a(dynload_shlib.o): In function `_PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr':
/Python-3.9.6/./Python/dynload_shlib.c:100: warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: Leaving directory '/Python-3.9.6'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:606: python] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:535: build_all_generate_profile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Python-3.9.6'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:511: profile-gen-stamp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Python-3.9.6'
make: *** [Makefile:523: profile-run-stamp] Error 2
```

And the full output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/2Wd8FLHs)

UPDATE:

When I enter the docker and this is the output for the commands:

```sh
[root@54c0d9495d37 /]# ld -lssl
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
[root@54c0d9495d37 /]# ld -lcrypto
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Comment: `dlopen` is an interface to the dynamic loader. By definition, it cannot be linked statically.

Comment: @DYZ I am not sure this is the issue, I think it fails on `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl` and `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto`

Comment: Do you _have_ static openssl libraries (`.a`, not `.so`)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how can I get it for centos 8? I see that `openssl-static` exists only for centos 7.9

Comment: _shrug_. Personally, I use [Nix](http://nixos.org/nix/) -- no matter what your OS, ask it to build `pkgsStatic.python3` and you get the same thing out. Not saying it doesn't exist or couldn't be built for CentOS, but I wouldn't spend the time myself.

Comment: (For that matter, ask Nix to build a Docker image with any given selection of software you want -- compiled with your choice of options -- and it'll do that too; see [dockerTools](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-pkgs-dockerTools). Doesn't help if you're wedded to CentOS, though).